# creating a SQL package to add arguments to views

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-view

I am working with a large data set and have created two views that work with this data set. The first (lets call this one View1) looks at the data and pulls certain values, the next view (lets call this one View2) looks at View1 and pulls certain values from that. The way I have it set up right now, if I inserted a WHILE statement into view 1 to restrict the days that are pulled from the large data set, this carries over to View2 as well (since View2 SELECTS FROM View1).

What I want to do is to create a package that will turn the start and end dates into variables so that I can do what the views are doing with dates I pass in instead of hard coding in the start and end dates each time.

I do not have a lot of experience with packages and have tried making one from some documentation I have found online, but to no avail.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I should add that I am working within Oracle SQL developer.

Comment: You shouldn't need a pacakge for this.  How are you currently calling the views?  You should just use a where clause and pass the parameters to the view that way.

Comment: I was thinking along those lines too, sadly I have to create a package to do this, I have no say in the matter. The goal is to use this to compare data in an external program. I guess thats why they want it all bundled into a package.

Comment: So not really views then. How will you call the package element (procedure or function), and how will you use the result? It sounds like you might want a pipelined function which returns the result of a simple join, but it's not very clear.